# Rust says import is not used and can't find imported statements at the same time

Tags: rust

I've got some structure I want to use Serde with. Like this one:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct GetLinkResponse {
    error: String,
    link: String,
}
```

But compiler says that:

1. `Serialize` import is not used
2. `Serialize` can't be found

```
error: cannot find derive macro `Serialize` in this scope
 --> src/structs.rs:3:10
  |
3 | #[derive(Serialize)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^

warning: unused imports: `Deserialize`, `Serialize`
 --> src/structs.rs:1:13
  |
1 | use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
  |             ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default
```

I guess I'm not understanding something about how *use* works. Can somebody explain me what is my mistake here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're victim of the "magic" behind automatic trait implementation, *i.e.* procedural macros. Usually, people give the procedural macro that implements a trait the same name as the trait (because it's convenient). Here, there is the trait `serde::Serialize`, but there is also the procedural macro that automatically implements that trait `serde::Serialize`.

They don't conflict because they live in difference namespaces, and the compiler infers from the context if it's a macro or a trait.

In your situation, you forgot to add the `derive` feature, so there is no proc macro in serde. Thus, you're importing a trait without using it, and you try to use a proc macro that doesn't exist.

The solution is to use the [serde's `derive` feature](https://serde.rs/derive.html):

```ini
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

or use the command line: `cargo add serde -F derive`

Comment: jeez, those features are killing my rust vibe :)

Comment: @TarasMatsyk Yeah, it's often a source of frustration, but you'll get used to it, and you'll understand quickly the source of the problem at a moment.